# Take a random sample from a dataframe making sure that I will keep at least one row for each column that has a value different from zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Player | Points | Assists | Rebounds | Steals | Blocks | Wins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bryant | 35 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| James | 24 | 11 | 9 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| Durant | 31 | 2 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Curry | 29 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Harden | 13 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Doncic | 12 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Buttler | 24 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Paul | 0 | 12 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 1 |

And I want to take a random sample from that dataframe, but in a way that in the resulting sample, each column will have at least one value different from 0. So for example if I decide to take a random sample of 3 players, those 3 players can't be James, Durant and Curry since all three of them have zeros on the Win column. They also couldn't be Bryant, Doncic and Paul since they all have zero blocks.

How can I do this ?

FWI: This dataframe is just a simplification, mine has a lot more of rows and columns, hence I need a generic answer or method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try something like this:

```
def sample_df(df, n=3):
    while True:
        dfs=df.sample(n)
        #print(dfs) Just added this print to show dataframes dropped do to zeroes
        if ~dfs.iloc[:,1:].sum().eq(0).any():
            return dfs

sample_df(df)
```

Output:

```
   Player  Points  Assists  Rebounds  Steals  Blocks  Wins
1   James      24       11         9       2       1     0
0  Bryant      35        5         5       1       0     1
2  Durant      31        2        12       0       0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I took myself the freedom to add a new player:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./data/players.csv')
_cols = list(df.columns)
_cols.remove('Player')
df['sum'] = df[_cols].sum(axis=1)
df
```

[image]

```
samples = 3
df[(df['sum']!=0)].sample(samples)
```

[image]

Unfortunately Marcello will never be sampled.

Comment: This won't necessarily work since what I need to be different than zero is the sum of each column and not the sum of the columns for each player. This solution may prohibit me for selecting Marcello but it still could select for example Bryant, Durant and Curry, which would make the sum of the 'Blocks' column to be zero.